# How to upcast to limit object properties

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript, how can I upcast from a subclass to superclass to automatically remove object properties that don't exist in superclass?

Example: assume the following 2 classes:

```
class ClassA {
  constructor(public a: string, public b: string) { }
}

class ClassB extends ClassA {
  constructor(public a: string, public b: string, public c: string) {
    super(a, b);
  }
}
```

Create an instance of ClassB:

```
let objB = new ClassB('a', 'b', 'c');
```

How can I strip fields that don't exist in `ClassA` from `objB` without specifying each field to be copied or removed? (ie. using spread or rest operators)

For example, in Java, one would cast to the superclass as below:

```
objA = (ClassA) objB;
```

Comment: Your Java example doesn't actually remove any properties.

Comment: @melpomene, it doesn't, but if you write objA to a database, for example, then only ClassA fields are written

Comment: That depends entirely on the code that does the writing.